# How to open a div with slideUp in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a div that I want when user click on a button `slideUp` in bottom of page and cover 30% of my page and if user click on that button my div `slideDown`.How I can do this?

thanks

**EDIT 1)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnWorks').on("click", function () {
            $('#tblWorks').slideToggle();
        });

    });
```

but it open from top to bottom.but I want open it from bottom to top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on where you have this element positioned or placed. If it's positioned absolute it may look like it slides up but it is really sliding down. When you call [`slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) it will [`slideDown()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) if the element is hidden, and [`slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) if the element is already visible.

jsFiddle of slideToggle, 2 examples: http://jsfiddle.net/HjJBZ/

You should put the element in a container div and slide the container div down instead which may work better.

Answer (score 3):

Check out some of jQuery's documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/

http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/

Comment: I know how I can use `slideUp` and `slideDown` but it open from top to bottom.but I want open it from bottom to top

Answer (score 2):

Try using jQuery's `slideToggle`.

http://jsfiddle.net/CLbzf/

```
$('#trigger').click( function() {
    $('#slider').slideToggle();
});​
```

Comment: it open from top to bottom.but I want open it from bottom to top

Comment: I don't get it.... it slides up from the bottom towards the top. How is that wrong?

Comment: you set posistion `fixed`.I should place my panel in bottom of my content

Comment: @Kerezo - Just switch it to absolute then and make sure the div doesn't have any parent ancestors that are relative or fixed.

Answer (score 0):

`slideUp` hides the elements, `slideDown` shows the elements. If you've anchored the elements via absolute positioning, you should still use `slideDown` to show the element, even though it might animate upwards.

Comment: I should place my panel in bottom of my page and I can't use absolut positioning

Comment: @Kerezo, do you mean `position: fixed`? My answer still stands, you'd still use `slideDown` to vertically show the selected elements, and `slideUp` to vertically hide them.